# How to extract a path with in a string (which contains multiple delimiters) using python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
string = "Some thing like, this, 'multiple delimiters', present, '', '','' ,'','File\Path\To\Extract.csv', '', '', String Ends"
```

I want to extract this csv file path `File\Path\To\Extract.csv` in the whole string.

Tried `string.split("'")[n]`, but my delimiters`'` are not fixed, it keeps on changing for each string.

Please highlight solution if you have come across this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you consider to be valid delimiters of the front/back of the path? Are you trying to match quotes? Are spaces allowed in the path elements (particularly, the leading/trailing elements)?

Comment: Thank you every one for helping me with solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, It does not require to import other packages. You can do this with string operations.

```
string = "Some thing like, this, 'multiple delimiters', present, '', '','' ,'','File\Path\To\Extract.csv', '', '', String Ends"
str_list=string.split("'")
for each in str_list:
    if each.endswith('csv'):
        print each
```

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

```
string = "Some thing like, this, 'multiple delimiters', present, '', '','' ,'','File\Path\To\Extract.csv', '', '', String Ends"

print string.split(",")[8][1:-1]
```

Or

```
print string.split("'")[11]
```

Or

```
for i in string.split("'"):
    if i.endswith("csv") and "\\" in i:
        print i
```

Output:

```
File\Path\To\Extract.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

use regex:

```
In [13]: import re

In [14]: s = "Some thing like, this, 'multiple delimiters', present, '', '','' ,'','File\Path\To\Extract.csv', '', '', String Ends"

In [15]: re.search(r"'([\w\\]+\.csv)'", s).group(1)
Out[15]: 'File\Path\To\Extract.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> string = "Some thing like, this, 'multiple delimiters', present, '', '','' ,'','File\Path\To\Extract.csv', '', '', String Ends"
>>> data_list = string.split(",")
>>> for data in data_list:
    if "csv" in data:
        print (data)        
'File\Path\To\Extract.csv'
```

Comment: Sorry to mention comma's & single quotes are not fixed in my string(keeps on changing)

Comment: In that case, I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for item in string.split(","):
  if ".csv" in item:
    print(item)
```